# Chaining Dependency Injection in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have the following code

```
services.AddSingleton<IFancyService>(new FancyServiceA());
services.AddSingleton<IFancyService>(new FancyServiceB());
services.AddSingleton<IFancyService>(new FancyServiceC());
```

For each implementation of `IFancyService`, I now want to inject a class that "decorates" the unique implementation of `IFancyService`. The code doing the decorating doesn't actually know about the implementations, it only knows about the interface.

Is there some way to do something like:

```
services.AddSingleton<IFancyServiceDecorator>(
    sp => new FancyServiceDecorator(sp.GetRequiredServices<IFancyService>()));
```

Which would ensure there is 3 instances of `IFancyServiceDecorator` registered (a decorator wrapping each of `FancyServiceA`, `FancyServiceB`, `FancyServiceC`) ?

My current implementation relies on something like this, which I am lead to believe is an anti-pattern due to the multiple instantiation of singletons:

```
var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var fancyServices = sp.GetRequiredService<IFancyService>();
foreach (var fs in fancyServices)
{
    services.AddSingleton(new FancyServiceDecorator(fs));
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try Scrutor `services.Decorate<IFancyServiceDecorator, FancyServiceA>()`

Comment: Decorating is not something that MS.DI supports. As @Aron noted, you can take a look at Scrutor, that builds on top of MS.DI, or take a look at one of the more mature DI Containers, as they almost all have support for decorators.

Comment: Additionally, since you only seem to need the singleton lifestyle and no need for Auto-Wiring, you can try making the registrations as follows: `services.AddSingleton<IFancyService>(new FancyServiceDecorator(new FancyServiceC()));`

Comment: "is an anti-pattern due to the multiple instantiation of singletons". With your given example, there won't be multiple singletons, because your `FancyService` implementations are not created by the container, but created once. Still, I do agree that you should prevent calling `BuildServiceProvider`, because it will lead to problems when -in the future- you decide to let the container create those singletons for you.

Comment: @Aron This is frustrating, as this codebase is a shared .net standard library and I'm trying to avoid adding more dependencies, especially for what boils down to the registration of one service.

Comment: @Steven The code doing the registration doesn't know about FancyServiceA/B/C, it only knows about the Interface. The example is super contrived but I'm trying to demonstrate the constraints without getting overly complicated.

Comment: If you don't want to take extra dependencies, you will have to re-implement what Scrutor is doing when it comes to applying decorators. But be aware that when adding decorators with MS.DI, there are certain limitations to consider. For instance: decorated instance will *never* get disposed of.

Comment: In general, DI registration should be the ONE place where everything is known. If this isn't the case, you might doing something else. For example, you might actually be doing plugins, in which case, you might want to take a look at MEF. However, I just can't see why your solution be structured such that the registration code knows about all your concrete types?

Comment: @Aron my Startup.cs definitely knows about all the concrete types. I was trying to write some extension methods in my .net standard shareable libraries which would do the service registration. I made the assumption that I could several things with the IServiceCollection that we could do with our previous DI Container (Structuremap) in my architecture that's causing a bunch of different problems now. This question wasn't phrased very well and I was mostly hoping for some guidance on syntax or internal workings of IServiceCollection that would allow me to work with collections of the same type.

Comment: I suggest reading [DI-Friendly Library](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/). In general libraries and frameworks should not be aware of (or reference) the DI container, but instead should be structured in a way that DI containers can easily (and optionally) work with them.